# Expression must have class type

Tags: c++

I am assuming this has something to do with the pointer, but here is my code that is having the error. Obviously I am not done yet, but the error is with the keys in the code below.

```
bool LCR_cipher::iskeysOK()
{
    vector<char> v(keys.begin(), keys.end());
    std::transform(v[0].begin(), v[0].end(), v[0].begin(), ::tolower);
}
```

Here is the header file

```
class LCR_cipher
{
public:
    // Constructor:
    LCR_cipher(char *context_string, char *keys_string);
    // Destructor: deallocate memory that was allocated dynamically
    ~LCR_cipher();
    //check whether *keys string has valid LCR encryption value
    bool iskeysOK();
    //encrypt context string
    void encryption();
    //unencrypt context string (optional)
    void unencryption();
    //check whether the context string is encrypted or not
    bool isencrypted();
    //Retrieve CLR encryption value from *keys string
    void getkeys(int& a, int& c);
    // output the *context to console
    void output_context();
private:
    char *context; //array to store context string
    char *keys; //array to store encryption keys
    bool encrypted; //whether string in *context is encrypted or not
    int context_MaxSize;
    int context_CurrentSize;
    int keys_MaxSize;
    int keys_CurrentSize;
```

}

Where did I go wrong here?

Comment: Please [edit] the error text returned by the compiler into the question

Comment: For starters your function isn't `return`ing anything, even though you declared it to return a `bool`

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
  v[0].begin()
```

v is a vector of char, so v[0] is a char, and chars don't have methods.

Comment: Oh, thank you for your quick reply. I didn't know chars don't have methods. Today I learned.